# In Java, why do we use "N.length-1" in arrays? What it really means?

Tags: java

```
int[] N = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for (int i = 0; i<N.length-1; i++){
    System.out.print.(N[i] + ",");
}
```

In the example above, why do we use N.length-1!!! is it because it's zero based index? so 10 = 11-1? This is very confusing!!!

Comment: Please be sure to search for answers before posting questions. This question has been asked and answered many times on this site, not to mention elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 2):

> In Java, why do we use “N.length-1” in arrays?

Because Java arrays are ["zero-based"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

An array of length= 1 has only element[0]; length= 2 element[0] and element[1], etc.

The "last element" always has an index of "length-1".

The reason for this is that the "index" (e.g. "0" for "element[0]") is equal to the *offset* from the beginning of the array (the "first" element has an offset of "zero").